# How to order based a belongs_to association through a polymorphic relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following tables in a rails 6 app:

```
Elections
has_many :coverages

Coverages
belongs_to :election
belongs_to :coverable, polymorphic

Dependents
belongs_to :relationship
has_many :coverages, as: :coverable

Employees
belongs_to :relationship
has_many :coverages, as: :coverable
```

I have a form for Elections that also submits nested attributes for coverages. I want to short the coverages based on their relationship type in the form. I've tried the following:

```
@election.coverages.order("coverable.relationship.id DESC")
```

This returns an error `missing FROM-clause entry for table "relationship"`

```
@election.coverages.joins(:coverable).order("relationship.id DESC")
```

This returns an error `Cannot eagerly load the polymorphic association :coverable`

Comment: You can't call coverages on the Election class. You can call it on an instance of the Election class. Try @election.coverages.order(id: :desc).

Comment: My mistake, I updated my question to use the instance of the election class. The `.order(id: :desc)`sorts on the id of the coverage, I'm trying to sort on the relationship_id (or on a value in the relationships table via the relationships) which is in both the employees and dependents tables via coverables since coverages can be either employees or dependents.